# How do I know my gemini.com's wallet's public key?

Tags: exchanges

Can I know my gemini.com's wallet's public key? gemini.com is an exchange which deals in BTC and ETH. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of two questions you might be asking:

1. *How do I know where to send ETH/BTC if I want to get it into my Gemini account?* Gemini will give you an address to send coins. E.g., when logged in, https://exchange.gemini.com/deposit/eth should show you an address.
2. *What's the address that's holding my ETH/BTC when it's in Gemini?* Here, I don't think there's a good answer. Gemini presumably holds different funds in different accounts, some probably "cold" (offline) to reduce the risk from hacking. The point is that *your* coins are held with everyone else's in accounts that Gemini controls. There is no account of yours that corresponds to just your funds.

If you'd like to move your ETH/BTC into an account you control, just create one and then transfer the funds out of Gemini and into that account.

Answer (score 0):

If I am trying to take money out of Gemini and put it in my Chase account, Do I have to change it to Gemini dollars and from there to my bank account? It ask me for a GUSD address and I am suppose to take a photo. What exactly am I suppose to photograph?

Comment: You should ask Gemini customer support.